# Neat Way to select every month in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, recursive-query

I am trying to find number of users every month.
This is my SQL which I learn from another question.

The part for creating number of month is easy to understand but it is long. I am wondering is there a neater way to write the same SQL. Thanks.

```
SELECT
    meses.MONTH,
    COUNT(Users.user_ID) AS num_of_user
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        1 AS MONTH
    UNION
SELECT
    2 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    3 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    4 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    5 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    6 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    7 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    8 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    9 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    10 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    11 AS MONTH
UNION
SELECT
    12 AS MONTH
) AS meses
LEFT JOIN
    Users
ON
    meses.month = MONTH(Users.joint_date) AND YEAR(Users.joint_date) = '2000'
GROUP BY
    meses.MONTN
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Incidentally, you only need the first 'AS MONTH'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query to generate the series.

I would also recommend filtering against literal dates rather than applying date function on the column being filtered: this is much more efficient, and can take advantage of an index on `users(joint_date)`.

```
with dates as (
    select '2020-01-01' dt
    union all select dt + interval 1 month from dates where dt + interval 1 month < '2021-01-01'
)
select d.dt, count(u.user_id) as num_of_users
from dates d
left join users u 
    on  u.joint_date >= d.dt
    and u.joint_date <  d.dt + interval 1 month
group by d.dt
```

In earlier versions, you do need to enumerate the dates, using `union`. However I would still recommend the literal date technique. That would look like:

```
select '2020-01-01' + interval n.n month as dt, count(u.user_id) as num_of_users
from (select 0 n union all select 2 ... union all select 11) n
left join users u 
    on  u.joint_date >= '2020-01-01' + interval n.n month
    and u.joint_date <  '2020-01-01' + interval (n.n + 1) month
group by n.n
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain/comment how your code works?